# Почему не получается принять сложный объект в контролере?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

Сабж. Есть проект WEB API, в нем есть контролер

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetRandomDouble(MinMax minMax) 
{
    return $"{minMax.Min} --------    {minMax.Min} ";
}
```

Код класса MinMax

```
public class MinMax
{
    public double Min { set; get; }

    public double Max { set; get; }
}
```

При запросе `/api/GetRandom?min=1&max=2` выдает

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-e07aa3c3d5673c43aea3e3f1b0d6d89b-8a8efb0e3c962647-00"
}
```

На сколько я понимаю это ошибка говорит о том что мол не те данные переданы в запросе. Но вроде же можно принять сложный объект, просто передать все заполненные поля и контролер сам все сопоставит.
Если делать точно такой же запрос но в контролере принимать два `double` то все работает.

В чем проблема?
Ну и может быть мне все это не надо, как лучше передавать объекты между микросервисами, мб просто `string` json?

Comment: [ASP.NET Core: FromQuery usage and URL format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741491/312041)